# Vagrant up on Ubuntu Jammy - cannot load such file -- rexml (LoadError)

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, vagrant-libvirt

I am trying to migrate from VirtualBox to libvirt and I have somme issues I can't work around and understand.
A colleague of mine has tested on a debian and all works fine for him.

**Describe the bug**
**To Reproduce**
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

```
git clone git@github.com:robinportigliatti/libvirt-test.git
cd libvirt-test
make up
```

```
Bringing machine 'host1' up with 'libvirt' provider...
Traceback (most recent call last):
    21: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.10/gems/vagrant-2.2.10/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    20: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.10/gems/vagrant-2.2.10/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:201:in `action'
    19: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.10/gems/vagrant-2.2.10/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:201:in `call'
    18: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.10/gems/vagrant-2.2.10/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:613:in `lock'
    17: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.10/gems/vagrant-2.2.10/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:215:in `block in action'
    16: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.10/gems/vagrant-2.2.10/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:243:in `action_raw'
    15: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.10/gems/vagrant-2.2.10/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:89:in `run'
    14: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.10/gems/vagrant-2.2.10/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    13: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.10/gems/vagrant-2.2.10/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:89:in `block in run'
    12: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.10/gems/vagrant-2.2.10/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:149:in `call'
    11: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.10/gems/vagrant-2.2.10/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
    10: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.10/gems/vagrant-2.2.10/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
     9: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.10/gems/vagrant-2.2.10/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
     8: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.10/gems/vagrant-2.2.10/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_check_outdated.rb:31:in `call'
     7: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.10/gems/vagrant-2.2.10/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
     6: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.10/gems/vagrant-2.2.10/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:47:in `call'
     5: from /home/robin/.vagrant.d/gems/2.6.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.9.0/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action.rb:99:in `block (2 levels) in action_up'
     4: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     3: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     2: from /home/robin/.vagrant.d/gems/2.6.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.9.0/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/resolve_disk_settings.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- rexml (LoadError)
```

**Expected behavior**
Machine host1 should be up

**Versions (please complete the following information):**:

- Libvirt version:

```
Compiled against library: libvirt 8.0.0
Using library: libvirt 8.0.0
Using API: QEMU 8.0.0
Running hypervisor: QEMU 6.2.0
```

- Vagrant version [output of `vagrant version`]:

```
Installed Version: 2.2.10
Latest Version: 2.2.19
 
To upgrade to the latest version, visit the downloads page and
download and install the latest version of Vagrant from the URL
below:

  https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html

If you're curious what changed in the latest release, view the
CHANGELOG below:

  https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/v2.2.19/CHANGELOG.md
```

- Vagrant flavour [Upstream or Distro]:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

- Vagrant plugins versions (including vagrant-libvirt) [output of `vagrant plugin list`]:

```
vagrant-libvirt (0.9.0, global)
vagrant-vbguest (0.30.0, global)
```

**Debug Log**
Attach Output of `VAGRANT_LOG=debug vagrant up --provider=libvirt >vagrant.log 2>&1`
[enter link description here](https://github.com/robinportigliatti/libvirt-test/blob/main/vagrant.log)

What I discovered is I had Ruby 3.0 installed on my machine and removed it.
Now I have only the embedded Ruby version of vagrant which is :

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby --version
ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x86_64-linux]
```

Thought about running `/opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/gem install rexml` but got the following error :

```
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rexml' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate) (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
```

Checked the certificates :

```
sudo /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/curl -Lks 'https://git.io/rg-ssl' | sudo /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby
Here's your Ruby and OpenSSL environment:

Ruby:           2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x86_64-linux]
RubyGems:       3.0.3
Bundler:        1.17.2
Compiled with:  OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
Loaded version: OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
SSL_CERT_FILE:  /opt/vagrant/embedded/cert.pem
SSL_CERT_DIR:   /opt/vagrant/embedded/certs

With that out of the way, let's see if you can connect to rubygems.org...

Bundler connection to rubygems.org:       failed  ❌  (certificate verification)
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
RubyGems connection to rubygems.org:      failed  ❌  (certificate verification)
Ruby net/http connection to rubygems.org: failed  ❌

Unfortunately, this Ruby can't connect to rubygems.org. 
Your Ruby can't connect to rubygems.org because you are missing the certificate files OpenSSL needs to verify you are connecting to the genuine rubygems.org servers.
```

Updated the certifcate :

```
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubygems/rubygems/master/lib/rubygems/ssl_certs/rubygems.org/GlobalSignRootCA_R3.pem
sudo cp GlobalSignRootCA_R3.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/GlobalSignRootCA_R3.pem
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Same error...

Any help is appreciated to help me fix my problem.

Robin,

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, from the vagrant tag: GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing all vagrant dependency and doing a clean install worked.

It was a bug from vagrant.

Best regards,